# C# python console

Tags: python, c#, console-application

Hope ur doing good! I have started making a console app last month(sorta like CMD in windows). i want to make a command in the program to start a python console the simplest way that I am thinking of is to make C# methods and the user will call those methods through input. But I don't want to write so many if statements, i want to convert the function and the param that user typed in the input into a line of code. so let's say i want to print "hello world", in python we type `print("hello world")` but when I make an input it is saved as a string, `'print("hello world")'`

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CMD
{
    class Program
    {
#pragma warning disable IDE0060
        static void Main(string[] args)
#pragma warning restore IDE0060
        {
            if (args is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(args));
            }

            Console.Clear();
            string inf = "1";
            while (inf == "1")
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("#- ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                string l1 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (l1 == "/out")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("out:");
                    string output = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(value: $"\n\n> {output}");
                }
                else if (l1 == "/in")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("in:");
                    string input = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(value: $"\n\n> {input}");
                    Console.ReadLine();


                }
                else if (l1 == "/clcltr")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("opr:");
                    string opr = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("num1:");
                    float num1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num2:");
                    float num2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (opr == "a")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1}\n{num2} = {num1 + num2}");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR - maybe you have typed the wrong operation or a character instead of number, please try again.\npress any key to close this window...");

                    }
                }
                else if (l1 == "/clcltr/2")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("opr:");
                    string opr = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("num1:");
                    float num1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num2:");
                    float num2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (opr == "a")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} + {num2} = {num1 + num2}");


                    }
                    if (opr == "s")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} - {num2} = {num1 - num2}");
                        Console.WriteLine("press any key to close this window...");

                    }
                    if (opr == "m")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} x {num2} = {num1 * num2}");
                        Console.WriteLine("press any key to close this window...");

                    }
                    if (opr == "d")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} / {num2} = {num1 / num2}");
                        Console.WriteLine("press any key to close this window...");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR - maybe you have typed the wrong operation or a character instead of number, please try again.\npress any key to close this window...");

                    }
                }
                else if (l1 == "/clcltr/3")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("opr:");
                    string opr = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("num1:");
                    float num1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num2:");
                    float num2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num3:");
                    float num3 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (opr == "a")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} + {num2} + {num3} = {num1 + num2 + num3}");
                        Console.WriteLine("press any key to close this window...");

                    }
                    else if (opr == "s")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} - {num2} - {num3} = {num1 - num2 - num3}");


                    }
                    else if (opr == "m")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} x {num2} x {num3} = {num1 * num2 * num3}");


                    }
                    else if (opr == "d")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} / {num2} / {num3} = {num1 / num2 / num3}");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR - maybe you have typed the wrong operation or a character instead of number, please try again.\npress any key to close this window...");

                    }
                }
                else if (l1 == "/clcltr/4")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("opr:");
                    string opr = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("num1:");
                    float num1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num2:");
                    float num2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num3:");
                    float num3 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num4:");
                    float num4 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (opr == "a")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} + {num2} + {num3} + {num4} = {num1 + num2 + num3 + num4}");


                    }
                    else if (opr == "s")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} - {num2} - {num3} - {num4} = {num1 - num2 - num3 - num4}");


                    }
                    else if (opr == "m")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} x {num2} x {num3} x {num4} = {num1 * num2 * num3 * num4}");


                    }
                    else if (opr == "d")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} / {num2} / {num3} / {num4} = {num1 / num2 / num3 / num4}");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR - maybe you have typed the wrong operation or a character instead of number, please try again.\npress any key to close this window...");

                    }
                }
                else if (l1 == "/clcltr/5")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("opr:");
                    string opr = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("num1:");
                    float num1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num2:");
                    float num2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num3:");
                    float num3 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num4:");
                    float num4 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num5:");
                    float num5 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (opr == "a")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} + {num2} + {num3} + {num4} + {num5} = {num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5}");


                    }
                    else if (opr == "s")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} - {num2} - {num3} - {num4} - {num5} = {num1 - num2 - num3 - num4 - num5}");


                    }
                    else if (opr == "m")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} x {num2} x {num3} x {num4} x {num5} = {num1 * num2 * num3 * num4 * num5}");


                    }
                    else if (opr == "d")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} / {num2} / {num3} / {num4} / {num5} = {num1 / num2 / num3 / num4 / num5}");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR - maybe you have typed the wrong operation or a character instead of number, please try again.\npress any key to close this window...");

                    }
                }
                else if (l1 == "/clcltr/6")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("opr:");
                    string opr = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("num1:");
                    float num1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num2:");
                    float num2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num3:");
                    float num3 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num4:");
                    float num4 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num5:");
                    float num5 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num6:");
                    float num6 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (opr == "a")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} + {num2} + {num3} + {num4} + {num5} + {num6} = {num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6}");


                    }
                    else if (opr == "s")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} - {num2} - {num3} - {num4} - {num5} - {num6} = {num1 - num2 - num3 - num4 - num5 - num6}");
                    }
                    else if (opr == "m")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} x {num2} x {num3} x {num4} x {num5} x {num6} = {num1 * num2 * num3 * num4 * num5 * num6}");
                    }
                    else if (opr == "d")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} / {num2} / {num3} / {num4} / {num5} / {num6} = {num1 / num2 / num3 / num4 / num5 / num6}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR - maybe you have typed the wrong operation or a character instead of number, please try again.\npress any key to close this window...");
                    }
                }
                else if (l1 == "/clcltr/7")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("opr:");
                    string opr = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("num1:");
                    float num1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num2:");
                    float num2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num3:");
                    float num3 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num4:");
                    float num4 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num5:");
                    float num5 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num6:");
                    float num6 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num7:");
                    float num7 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (opr == "a")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} + {num2} + {num3} + {num4} + {num5} + {num6} + {num7} = {num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7}");
                    }
                    else if (opr == "s")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} - {num2} - {num3} - {num4} - {num5} - {num6} - {num7} = {num1 - num2 - num3 - num4 - num5 - num6 - num7}");
                    }
                    else if (opr == "m")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} x {num2} x {num3} x {num4} x {num5} x {num6} x {num7} = {num1 * num2 * num3 * num4 * num5 * num6 * num7}");
                    }
                    else if (opr == "d")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} / {num2} / {num3} / {num4} / {num5} / {num6} / {num7} = {num1 / num2 / num3 / num4 / num5 / num6 / num7}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR - maybe you have typed the wrong operation or a character instead of number, please try again.\npress any key to close this window...");
                    }
                }
                else if (l1 == "/clcltr/8")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("opr:");
                    string opr = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("num1:");
                    float num1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num2:");
                    float num2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num3:");
                    float num3 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num4:");
                    float num4 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num5:");
                    float num5 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num6:");
                    float num6 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num7:");
                    float num7 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("num8:");
                    float num8 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (opr == "a")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} + {num2} + {num3} + {num4} + {num5} + {num6} + {num7} + {num8} = {num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8}");
                    }
                    else if (opr == "s")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} - {num2} - {num3} - {num4} - {num5} - {num6} - {num7} + {num8}  = {num1 - num2 - num3 - num4 - num5 - num6 - num7 - num8}");
                    }
                    else if (opr == "m")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} x {num2} x {num3} x {num4} x {num5} x {num6} x {num7} x {num8}  = {num1 * num2 * num3 * num4 * num5 * num6 * num7 * num8}");
                    }
                    else if (opr == "d")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{num1} / {num2} / {num3} / {num4} / {num5} / {num6} / {num7} / {num8}  = {num1 / num2 / num3 / num4 / num5 / num6 / num7 / num8}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR - maybe you have typed the wrong operation or a character instead of number, please try again.\npress any key to close this window...");
                    }
                }
                else if (l1 == "/ping")
                {
                    using var ping = new Ping();
                    Console.Write("/pingAddress: ");
                    var reply = ping.Send(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Pinging with server... " + reply.Address);
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success!!");
                    }
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.TimedOut)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The Server was timed out.");
                    }
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Unknown) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Address!");
                    }
                }
                else if (l1 == "/light")
                {
                    Console.Write("Are You Sure? The Whole screen will be cleared (y/n, default 'n'): ");
                    string per = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (per == "y")
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                    else { }
                }
                else if (l1 == "/dark")
                {
                    Console.Write("Are You Sure? The Whole screen will be cleared (y/n, default 'n'): ");
                    string per = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (per == "y")
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                    else { }
                }
                else if (l1 == "/write")
                {
                    Console.Write("User: ");
                    string User = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write($@"Save As: C:\Users\{User}\");
                    string FName = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t3 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t4 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t5 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t6 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t7 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t8 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t9 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t10 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t11 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t12 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t13 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t14 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t15 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t16 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t17 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t18 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t19 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string t20 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string txt = $"{t1}\n{t2}\n{t3}\n{t4}\n{t5}\n{t6}\n{t7}\n{t8}\n{t9}\n{t10}\n{t11}\n{t12}\n{t13}\n{t14}\n{t15}\n{t16}\n{t17}\n{t18}\n{t19}\n{t20}";
                    File.WriteAllText($@"C:\Users\{User}\{FName}", txt);
                    Console.WriteLine($@"find your file in: 'C:\Users\{User}\{FName}'");
                }
                else if (l1 == "clear")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                else if (l1 == "cls")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                else if (l1 == "help")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("    1. /out: \n   this command is used to show output in the console.");
                    Console.WriteLine("    2. /in: \n   this command is used to make a simple input in the console.");
                    Console.WriteLine("    3. /clcltr/2 or /clcltr: \n   this command is used to apply an arithmetic operation with two floats.");
                    Console.WriteLine("    4. /clcltr/3: \n    this command is used to apply an arithmetic operation with three floats.");
                    Console.WriteLine("    5. /clcltr/4: \n    this command is used to apply an arithmetic operation with four floats.");
                    Console.WriteLine("    6. /clcltr/5: \n    this command is used to apply an arithmetic operation with five floats.");
                    Console.WriteLine("    7. /clcltr/6: \n    this command is used to apply an arithmetic operation with six floats.");
                    Console.WriteLine("    8. /clcltr/7: \n    this command is used to apply an arithmetic operation with seven floats.");
                    Console.WriteLine("    9. /clcltr/8: \n    this command is used to apply an arithmetic operation with eight floats.");
                    Console.WriteLine("   10. /ping: \n    this command is used to send 4 packets, each of 20 bytes of data and send and recieve it to the local device.");
                }
                else if (l1 == "/py")
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write(">>> ");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    void print(string txt)
                    {
                        Console.Write(txt);
                    }
                }
                else if (l1 == "") { }
                else if (l1 == "exit")
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"'{l1}' is not recognised as a command\n type 'help' for all commands");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code for the python console command:

```cs
else if (l1 == "/py")
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write(">>> ");
    Console.ReadLine();
    void print(string txt)
    {
        Console.Write(txt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/)?

Comment: can u tell me how i will use it in visual studio?

Comment: cuz all i see is hundreds of python files